# composer update unrecognized make command

Tags: php, composer-php

When im trying to update composer with composer update this happens.

```
  Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Executing script make cache-warmup [KO]
 [KO]
Script make cache-warmup returned with error code 1
!!  'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
!!  operable program or batch file.
!!  
!!
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply missing the make command on your system.

Just install it.

***On windows*** via **CYGWIN** if you didn't got cygwin and you don't want to install it cos ..., you got an alternative with gnu binary for windows here you go : http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm

***On linux*** depend of your OS but :

sudo apt-get install make

> Take care on incompatibilities no sure if this intall will solve your
>   problem.

Comment: Kinda weird i could run this in my first project. But not now

Comment: The error message *"... is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."* identifies the OS as Windows and the shell as the standard Windows Command Prompt.